# Opencv videocapture can not open 4 cameras simultaneously

Tags: c++, opencv, usb, video-capture, usb-camera

I have four usb camers mounted via usb hub. they are video4,video6,video8 and video10. When I open the camera one by one, they works fine.

When I open three cameras together, they still works fine.

But when I open four cameras together, the fourth camera can not capture anything.

Here is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main()
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap1(10, cv::CAP_V4L);
    cap1.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 352);
    cap1.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 288);
    cap1.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'));

    cv::VideoCapture cap2(8, cv::CAP_V4L);
    cap2.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 352);
    cap2.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 288);
    cap2.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'));

    cv::VideoCapture cap3(6, cv::CAP_V4L2);
    cap3.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 352);
    cap3.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 288);
    cap3.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'));

    cv::VideoCapture cap4(4, cv::CAP_V4L2);
    cap4.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 352);
    cap4.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 288);
    cap4.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'));
    while (true)
    {
        cv::Mat img1, img2, img3, img4;
        cap1.grab();
        cap1.retrieve(img1);
        cap2.grab();
        cap2.retrieve(img2);
        cap3.grab();
        cap3.retrieve(img3);
        cap4.grab();
        cap4.retrieve(img4);
        
     
        

        if (img1.cols > 0)
        {
            cv::imshow("1", img1);
            cv::waitKey(50);
        }
        if (img2.cols > 0)
        {
            cv::imshow("2", img2);
            cv::waitKey(50);
        }
        if (img3.cols > 0)
        {
            cv::imshow("3", img3);
            cv::waitKey(50);
        }
        if (img4.cols > 0)
        {
            cv::imshow("4", img4);
            cv::waitKey(50);
        }

    }

    return 1;
}
```

the output like this:
[outputimg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc7Yx.png)

only first three images can be obtained.the fourth camera capture nothing.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks for your attentation.

my usb devices is shown in this figure:
[lsusb -t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewP3N.png)
[lsusb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue8cx.png)

I have tried to open camera by V4L2, and change the resolution. the fourth camera still not work.

Comment: Can you do a sanity check? Try opening the 4th camera by itself, after this swap the 1st and 4th camera and open all 4.

Comment: likely devices run into USB hub bandwidth limit (480M), either because all the MJPEG streams already use up enough of it, or because the FOURCC set calls happened in an unfortunate order, such that the cameras get opened without it, i.e. uncompressed.

Comment: please insert *text*, not screenshots of text.

Comment: are you able to run all the cameras together if you start 4 different applications, where each of the application runs 1 camera? You should check the return values of grab and retrieve.

Comment: Finally, the camera works after I mount two cameras in one usb port, and others in another usb port.